# What are the minimum pilot certification and flight time to serve as SIC under Part 135?

Tags: faa-regulations, far-135

What are the minimum pilot certification and flight hours to serve as SIC under Part 135 in a normal, fixed-wing operation?

Comment: Jet or turboprop? VFR or IFR?

Comment: @PilotDan Why not address the different mins for those possibilities in an answer?

Answer (score 2):

[135.245](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=dd19daafffcab442e50d0ba1b8326aa7&mc=true&node=se14.3.135_1245&rgn=div8) specifies the SIC need only have a commercial certificate with Category and Class, as well as an instrument rating. No minimum time is mentioned.